# Switch webpage from IE Metro to IE10 Desktop Version

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, internet-explorer-10

I need to create a way so that when users load our webpage inside IEmetro it switches them to IE10 Desktop automatically. Reason behind this is our website features won't work in IEmetro. our site is built in Aspx and cs code, java script and uses some jquery at times.

Does anyone have an idea how we can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any control over what browser the user is using; and there is no reason why your site should not work in Internet Explorer in the Modern UI (formerly 'Metro'). The two browsers are nearly identical in just about every way.

If you're having problems working with Internet Explorer 10, please ask a more specific question here and/or work through the [Internet Explorer 10 Guide for Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673549%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

I would also be interested in this.

IEMetro unfortunately has a number of features disabled, and shows javascript alerts differently drastically altering the user experience.